# How to create a new model?

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I wish I could do the following: `@Html.MvcSiteMap().PageMenu()` instead of `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("MenuBtnGroup")`.

Mainly because of the filters.

I wish that a certain link to appear only on the page or sitemap and not in the main application menu

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Usuários" controller="Usuarios" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Novo Usuário" action="Novo" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,PAGEMENU-ONLY,!*" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Detalhes" action="Detalhes" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" dynamicNodeProvider="UsuarioDynamicNodeProvider, Web">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Editar" action="Editar" inheritedRouteParameters="id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality isn't built-in (yet), but there is a way to make it happen by building your own visibility provider and using the SourceMetaData to pass the name of the menu into the visibility logic.

```
/// <summary>
/// Filtered SiteMapNode Visibility Provider for use with named controls.
/// 
/// Rules are parsed left-to-right, first match wins. Asterisk can be used to match any control or any control name. Exclamation mark can be used to negate a match.
/// </summary>
public class CustomFilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider
    : SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderBase
{
    #region ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the node is visible.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="node">The node.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceMetadata">The source metadata.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the specified node is visible; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsVisible(ISiteMapNode node, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        // Is a visibility attribute specified?
        string visibility = string.Empty;
        if (node.Attributes.ContainsKey("visibility"))
        {
            visibility = node.Attributes["visibility"].GetType().Equals(typeof(string)) ? node.Attributes["visibility"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visibility))
        {
            return true;
        }
        visibility = visibility.Trim();

        // Check for the source HtmlHelper
        if (sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"] == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        string htmlHelper = sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString();
        htmlHelper = htmlHelper.Substring(htmlHelper.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        string name = sourceMetadata["name"].ToString();

        // All set. Now parse the visibility variable.
        foreach (string visibilityKeyword in visibility.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }))
        {
            if (visibilityKeyword == htmlHelper || visibilityKeyword == name || visibilityKeyword == "*")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (visibilityKeyword == "!" + htmlHelper || visibilityKeyword == "!" + name || visibilityKeyword == "!*")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Still nothing? Then it's OK!
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can just name each of your menus by giving them a "name" SourceMetadata attribute.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "MainMenu" })
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "PageMenu" })
```

And then use the CustomFilteredSiteMapVisibilityProvider instead of the FilteredVisibilityProvider in your configuration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625384/how-to-render-specific-sitemap-section-using-mvcsitemapprovider#19666647) for a complete example.